# zbar barcode scanning from only image no image view or camera roll

Tags: ios, barcode-scanner, zbar

Hi if i make a image capture screen with this

```
-(void)initializecam{
     AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.layer;
NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.bounds;
[captureVideoPreviewLayer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];
[self.vImagePreview.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];
_stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[_stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:_stillImageOutput];
[session startRunning];
}
```

So now i want to use zbar bar code scanning. Any one know how to do this. I searched a lot but all there is they use the image capture view and how to modify that view. All i need is that i have an image[not in camera roll] and i want to scan it by zbar no image capture view or anything. Please help. Is there is any other free library except zbar to do this??

Answer (score 1):

it can be done by this

```
 - (void)scan {
// ADD: present a barcode reader that scans from the camera feed

    ZBarReaderController *reader = [ZBarReaderController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;

    // EXAMPLE: disable rarely used I2/5 to improve performance
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                   config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                       to: 0];

    CGImageRef imgCG = self.imgCameraView.image.CGImage;

id<NSFastEnumeration> results = [reader scanImage:imgCG];
ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
for(ZBarSymbol *symbolF in results){
    // EXAMPLE: just grab the first barcode
    symbol=symbolF;
    break;
}

if([symbol.data length]>0){
    NSLog(@"Bar Code ID = %@",symbol.data);
    self.ticketCode=symbol.data;

    [self verifybarCode];
    self.vImagePreview.hidden=FALSE;
}
else
{
[[iToast makeText:AMLocalizedString(@"Image Is Not Properly Scanned\nTry Again", nil)] show];
self.vImagePreview.hidden=FALSE;
}

}
```

Previously i was taking ZBarReaderViewController

Comment: Hey do you know how to add optical zoom programmatically?

Comment: i didn't try that one. I will try and let you known. Need to set optical zoom while scanning the barcode right?

Comment: Yes. I ve used my own camera view and send the image to the zbar scanner that is why.